# Make superuser act like some other user in certain directory tree

Tags: permissions, sudo, nfs, su

I have the following problem:

My home directory lies on the network and is mounted locally on `home/<my username>`.
I can access it with my normal user account `<my username>`, but as root, I cannot.

I *do* know about this question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/571073/root-cannot-access-users-home-folder-shared-via-nfs

However, this, from my limited understanding of linux systems etc., seems to be some server-side-solution, if it's even applicable in this case.

But I need a client-side solution, since the admins won't change this for the time being.

So I was wondering if there was some sort of option to make the superuser  **automatically** act like user `<my username>` inside the sub-directory-tree `/home/<my username>`, whenever the superuser needs access there.
As of now, the superuser can't even `cd` into my home directory.

Please note, the solution should work for `sudo` *and* in case I choose to `sudo su`.

Comment: That's `root_squash` at work, alright, so it is applicable. I take it you can't change the permissions for the paths leading to your home directory?

Comment: nope... not my turf ;(

Answer (score 0):

You can change users using `su` like follows:

```
root@bacon [~]# whoami
root
root@bacon [~]# su - cataline
cataline@bacon [/root]# whoami
cataline
```

May need to use sudo to run the command depending on permissions.

**EDIT** Changed command to reflect creating a login shell